# h2o in python, how to get glm multiclassification coefficients?

Tags: python, h2o

Working with h2o in python, how do you extract the model coefficients from a 'glm' multiclassification model?

For a binary model, you simply use .coef() or .coef_norm() methods, but these both return an error with multiclassification models.

In the R version of h2o, it is very simple: model@model$coefficients_table will work just fine.

So im not sure why its so much more difficult in Python. Is there a different method I need to be using, or do you have to somehow manually iterate over the base one-vs-all models and extract the model coefficients somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out about the backend json data, I was able to find this:

```
variable_importances = model._model_json['output']['coefficients_table'].as_data_frame()
```